# relative paths: difference between "./" and "../" ?

Tags: path, relative-path

I'm  struggling to find the answer of the difference between ./ and ../ in relative paths . 
I know *../somepath* will look in the parent folder, but where do *./somepath* and */somepath* point at ?

Comment: /somepath is somepath from root directory and ./somepath is path from current directory

Comment: `./` is the current directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Menu>Inner>Core

If you are inside Inner folder,
./menu will point to nothing since there is no menu folder inside Inner folder,
/core will point to Core folder.

Comment: No, if you are inside `Inner`, `./menu` won't point at _anything_. That would look for something called `menu` inside `Inner`, not go up a level. There isn't a `menu` inside `Inner` here. And `/core` would _also_ not point at anything. It would look for something called `core` at the very top level of the directory tree, which you haven't shown. Finally, please don't assume that filesystems are case-insensitive. That's not a valid assumption. Unless... are you drawing your filesystem backwards? What do you mean by `>`? Please be as clear as possible. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

- ./ points to your current folder/directory
- ../ points to the Parent folder/directory ie) One level up
- and / points to the root folder

Eg: Root/Parent/Current.txt